# Animate in curve in layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, caanimation

I have been trying to do this for several days. I have an array of CGPoints that can form either a curve or straight line(freehand). I am using CALayer and want to animate it in a smoothly(like a circular path). So far this is what i have tried. The code below i found on some link but it doesnt animate smoothly. Need some help fellows thx in advance

```
  curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    const int TOTAL_POINTS = 3;
    int horizontalWiggle = 15;
                    CGPoint viewOrigin = [[arrOfLocations objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
                    CGPoint endPoint = [[arrOfLocations lastObject] CGPointValue];

    int stepChangeX = (endPoint.x - viewOrigin.x) / TOTAL_POINTS;
    int stepChangeY = (endPoint.y - viewOrigin.y) / TOTAL_POINTS;

    for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_POINTS; i++) {
        int startX = (int)(viewOrigin.x + i * stepChangeX);
        int startY = (int)(viewOrigin.y + i * stepChangeY);

        int endX = (int)(viewOrigin.x + (i+1) * stepChangeX);
        int endY = (int)(viewOrigin.y + (i+1) * stepChangeY);

        int cpX1 = (int)(viewOrigin.x + (i+0.25) * stepChangeX);
        if((i+1)%2) {
            cpX1 -= horizontalWiggle;
        } else {
            cpX1 += horizontalWiggle;
        }
        int cpY1 = (int)(viewOrigin.y + (i+0.25) * stepChangeY);

        int cpX2 = (int)(viewOrigin.x + (i+0.75) * stepChangeX);
        if((i+1)%2) {
            cpX2 -= horizontalWiggle;
        } else {
            cpX2 += horizontalWiggle;
        }
        int cpY2 = (int)(viewOrigin.y + (i+0.75) * stepChangeY);

        CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, startX, startY);
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, cpX1, cpY1, cpX2, cpY2, endX, endY);
```

And to Animate Layer.I used

```
 CAKeyframeAnimation *keyFrameAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
                    keyFrameAnimation.delegate = self;
                    //        [keyFrameAnimation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationPaced];
                    keyFrameAnimation.duration = 1;
                    keyFrameAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
                    [keyFrameAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
                    keyFrameAnimation.path = curvedPath2;

arrayOfAnimations addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:basicAni,@"name",[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],@"toValue",@"appear",@"type", nil] ];
            [self animationHandler];


- (void)animationHandler{
    isAnimationInProgress = YES;
    NSDictionary * dict = [arrayOfAnimations objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * idd = [dict objectForKey:@"type"];
    if ([idd isEqualToString:@"path"]) {

        CGPoint p =  [[dict valueForKey:@"toValue"]CGPointValue];
        CAKeyframeAnimation *keyF = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        keyF.delegate = self;
        pointerLayer.position = p;
        [pointerLayer addAnimation:keyF forKey:@"path"];
    }
    else
    {
        int p =  [[dict valueForKey:@"toValue"]intValue];
        pointerLayer.opacity = p;
        CABasicAnimation *basic = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        basic.delegate = self;
        [pointerLayer addAnimation:basic forKey:@"opacity"];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CAShapeLayer`... you can animate its `path` property.

Comment: What i have found about CAShapeLayer is for animating shape.... but i want to animated the position in curved path.. with given CGPoints that form a circular path

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Why can't you use a shape layer and animate it's position, or apply a rotation animation to it?

Comment: IT doesn't move the position of layer but draw another object using the CGPoints and moves its position.

Answer (score 0):

K i found where i was mistaking..... i achieved what i was looking for to some extent...i was creating the path wrong. I created the path from code below. it animates the layer in circular if the CGPoints in array form a circular ... but it has now has some jerks.

```
CGPoint p1 = [[arrOfLocations objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint p2 = [[arrOfLocations objectAtIndex:i+1] CGPointValue];

        CGFloat x = p2.x-p1.x;
        CGFloat y = p2.y-p1.y;

        CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath2, NULL, p1.x, p1.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(curvedPath2, NULL, p2.x, p2.y);
```